# Special regex rule for wordlist

Tags: regex

How do I create a proper regex rule to the following rules?

- Must contain at least one number.
- Must contain at least one alphabetic character `a-z`.
- No more than 4 of the same number or letter in a row.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: "No more than 4 of the continuous number or letter in a row. No more than 4 of the same number or letter in a row". -- I think that It can be summed to: No more than 4 of the same number or letter in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**lookaheads**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and [**back referencing**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*(.)\1{3}).*$
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/sW6yI8/3)

**Edit:** If you do not wish to match strings that have white space characters, you can do:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?!.*(.)\1{3})\S*$ // replaced the . at the end with \S
```

Comment: you motivate me to finally learn lookaheads and backreferencing :)

Comment: @Gewure Glad to have helped. You're in the right place for learning regex in general. There's a never-ending supply of regex questions and resources on SO.

Comment: @timolawl Good job, but it doesn't handle expressions like this one: "qave4444". Any Idea why? (I don't know lookaheads and back referencing also).

Comment: @MaxG Ah forgot to add the `.*` to the negative lookahead. Fixed.

Comment: yeah its works with .* thank you very much timolawl ^^